# Change Contact Form Colors

Tags: html, css, forms

I'm trying to change a couple of the colors of the contact form on our site https://haaswoodworking.com/contact.html, specifically the dark grey color that appears when you click into a field and the light blue color that appears when you finish a field.

Any guidance for a beginner would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to look into both HTML and CSS.  These should be good starting places. https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp https://www.w3schools.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

Change line 1101 of https://haaswoodworking.com/css/1-style.css

```
input[type="text"]:focus,
input[type="password"]:focus,
input[type="email"]:focus,
input[type="tel"]:focus,
select:focus,
textarea:focus {
    background: #444444; /* <-- Change this */
    border-color: transparent;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Make sure you put in the hex color

Comment: Thanks! I'm using a very poor website builder. Would you mind holding my hand a bit and let me know exactly what would need to go in the custom CSS or HTML areas? Is it just a copy of that with updated color?

Comment: Yes basically. Like if you want green then you'd make it `background: #00FF00` or whatever. If you need the hex of a color just search 'blue hex' or 'brown hex' on google.

Comment: Thanks. Again because I know nothing about code and because I'm using a random site builder without access to the full backend, to modify this field would I need to copy the entire chunk you listed above into an are of the site builder that allows for custom HTML for the entire site (not just specific to this contact widget) or opy the entire chunk you listed above into an are of the site builder that allows for custom CSS for the entire site (not just specific to this contact widget) or ?

Comment: What site builder are you using?

Comment: FastComent (created the site for a friend who had already had a subscription to the service / is hosting their domain on it). I have a custom CSS option for the contact widget, and then a similar option + HTML at the site level as well. I have 0 expertise outside of the drag and drop, hence the questions...